# Hadoop pig latin unable to stream through a python script

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-pig

I have a simple python script (moo.py) that i am trying to stream though

```
import sys, os
for line in sys.stdin:
    print 1;
```

and i try to run this pig script

```
DEFINE CMD `python moo.py` ship('moo.py');
data = LOAD 's3://path/to/my/data/*' AS (a:chararray, b:chararray, c:int, d:int);
res = STREAM data through CMD;
dump res;
```

when i run this pig script local (pig -x local) everything is fine,
but when i run it without -x local, it prints out this error

> [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2017: Internal error creating job configuration.

[Log file]

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File moo.py does not exist.

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i used `ship()` function instead of `cache()`
while `ship()` works file - passing local files from the master to the slaves
`cache()` is used by the slaves to obtain files from an accessible place 
such as s3 on amazon

hope that helps anyone :]

Answer (score 5):

it's most likely an issue of relative path.

try:

```
DEFINE CMD `python moo.py` ship('/local/path/to/moo.py');
```

it can also be an issue of read/write/execute permission.